# How to make nginx recognice services.php/WebServiceSomething to services.php

Tags: php, web-services, nginx, apache-axis, wsh

Maybe the title is not happy, but i could explain better.

I need to make nginx do the next...

When i get the URL:

http://someurl.com/system/xx/services.php/SomethingWebService

I need to be resolved by services.php but the REQUEST URI not altered...

This is the first step... then i need to be able to receive parameters example:

http://someurl.com/services.php/SomethingWebService?wsdl

Is it posible?... in apache works fine... im new at nginx and i need to use it because apache is going down of performance... the aplication cant be changed because is third party... so is not an option... any idea?